# PhpMailer - Print who the message is sent to

Tags: php, echo, phpmailer

I've got a script working with PHPMailer, and have an if statement at the bottom with the standard 'Message Sent'

What I really want in that statement is 'message sent to email@address.com.' With the email address the message went to.

Is this easily done?

Thanks

Comment: uh, how it hard is it to change `echo "sent"` to `echo "sent to $address"`?

Answer (score 1):

Like our friend [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) said, you can add the `$recipient` to your text. Like for example :

```
$recipient = 'mail@example.com';
// ...
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent to $recipient';
}
```

Any details let me know plz.

Good luck.